# Как добавить маршалинг строки в функцию библиотеки, которая добавлена через reference?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, кодировка

У меня подключена библиотека (неуправляемая) через reference

```
    using TPLib;
```

и успешно с ней работаю с англоязычным текстом. Сейчас нужно добавить поддержку русского (кодировка нужная со слов разработчика 1251, но в документации BSTR)

Поэтому я дополнительно вытаскиваю из нее нужную функцию но с маршалингом строки

```
    [DllImport("TPLib.dll")]
    private static extern TABase ProcessText([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string text)
```

Но для работоспособности этой функции нужен внутренний элемент класса TPLib, который у меня не получается достать с помощью DLLImport. (Если я при `using TPLib` сделаю этот `dllimport`, функция с маршалингом не используется, а дефолтная)

Есть ли способ добавить маршалинг избегая DLLImport?

Алсо - нужно ли при маршалинге что-то делать перед отправкой string в функцию? Или просто передать ему читаемую в Unicode строку, и он сам ее подгонит под нужную кодировку?

---

В документации функция выглядит так

```
HRESULT ProcessText(BSTR text, [out, retval] IDispatch** pIBase,);
```

---

[image: метаданные]

Comment: Если библиотека неуправляемая, то как же она  подключена  через reference ?

Comment: @JaponDemon Это COM. По крайней мере пока не нашлось способов как то дополнить эту библиотеку

Comment: BSTR подразумевает кодировку utf-16, которая может передавать любые символы (в т.ч. русский алфавит), в каком именно месте у вас слетает кодировка?

Comment: Комментарий от разработчика -  для русского языка используется собственный словарь, который использует 1251 (он так же сказал что нужно передавать текст в 1251, от этого я и отталкивалась и даже не обращала внимание что BSTR указан)

Т.е. если  я для этого ProcessText использую английский словарь и любой текст - все обрабатывается. 
Если я начинаю брать русский словарь - ессно ничего не работает

Comment: @ОльгаОмельчишина а  ссылку на библиотеку не добавите?.  Может что-нибудь прояснится.

Comment: библиотека технологии анализа текстов TextAnalyst - это оно ?

Comment: @JaponDemon да, все верно. 
Тут можно почитать и найти ссылку для скачивания  http://www.interface.ru/home.asp?artId=33240
(нужные dll: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Zf9QMbtRiR2fLXJO_6UO1eoXgkq_I6ga )

Comment: Если это COM, к чему тут голое определение функции с DllImport? Или к COM прилагаются еще обычные функции? "функция с маршалингом не используется, а дефолтная" - Что за дефолтная?

Comment: "[out, retval] IDispatch" - это больше похоже на синтаксис определения метода интерфейса в IDL, чем на синтаксис сишной функции.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight под дефолтной имелась в виду та, что получена из подключении библиотеки через reference.

Половина действий стрельба в пустоту, в этой теме (dll, com) ровно столько, сколько пытаюсь решить эту проблему - дней 5. DLL import из за того что библиотека содержится в .dll файле, не более.
Я слабо представляю устройство данной библиотеки, при написании когда использовались примеры из документации

Comment: у вас ProcessText - метод интерфейса, а не функция.Вам надо не DLLImport делать, а скопировать к себе в код **весь** интерфейс и поменять в нем что нужно. Но навскидку могу сказать, что если метод берет BSTR и при этом не обрабатывает русский язык - дело не в маршаллинге и кодировке, а вообще в чем то другом.